# Time slicer in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

This is sample of values appearing in my time custom column:

[image]

Part of formula that generated this custom column goes like this:

```
RETURN FORMAT( TIME(hr; mn;ss); "HH:mm:ss" ))
```

so this column suppose to be in "time" format.

But in visuals this column is recognized as text with discrete values. Is there a way to define it as time and use it as slicer/filter which is time based?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the modeling tab, make sure the data type for your calculated column is set to 'Time'. 
[image]

Comment: That fixed it. I can't believe I missed that. I guess I expected that if I defined it with RETURN command to be type of TIME that I don't have to check type in Modeling tab. I guess this is bug. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped. Also, it's not really a bug since return value type for FORMAT function is the string: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/format-function-dax